# typo3 language menu with typoscript files not found

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

I try to add a language menu with typoscript, but the files I want to add as images ar not working.

my typoscript looks like this:

```
## Localization menu:
temp.langMenu = HMENU
    temp.langMenu.special = language
    temp.langMenu.special.value = 0,2
    temp.langMenu.1 = GMENU
    temp.langMenu.1.NO {
    XY = [5.w]+4, [5.h]+4
    backColor = white
    5 = IMAGE
    5.file = fileadmin/bilder/DE-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/US-flag-32.png
    5.offset = 2,2
    }

    temp.langMenu.1.ACT < lib.langMenu.1.NO
    temp.langMenu.1.ACT = 1
    temp.langMenu.1.ACT.backColor = black

    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1 < lib.langMenu.1.NO
    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1 = 1
    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1.5.file = fileadmin/bilder/DE-flag-32.png || fileadmin/bilder/US-flag-32.png
    temp.langMenu.1.USERDEF1.noLink = 1
```

Cache is clean ...

result is this:

[image]

links are working but no image. in Site-source code the image got this path:

```
<img src="/typo3temp/menu/4baf3d2e70.gif" width="36" height="36" alt="Home">
```

Whats my Mistake in this case

Comment: Image generation on the server (the install tool checks) is working in general? Pay special attention to the GDlib tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Image generation on the server (the install tool checks) is working in general? Pay special attention to the GDlib tests

install of imagemagick does the job

Answer (score 1):

I usually have a similar approach:

```
temp.language = HMENU
temp.language {
  special = language
  // 0 = Deutsch, 1 = Englisch
  special.value = 0,1
  wrap = <ul class="langmenu">|</ul>
  1 = GMENU
  1 {
    NO = 1
    NO {
      format = png
      // size of flag grafics
      XY = 38,17
      transparentColor = #00FFFF     
      backColor = #00FFFF      
      10 = IMAGE
      10.file = fileadmin/flags/de.png || fileadmin/flags/uk.png
      10.offset = 10,0
      10.file.width = 28
      10.file.height = 17

      wrap = <li>|</li>
    }
    ACT < .NO
    ACT {
      20 = IMAGE
      20.file = fileadmin/flags/arrow.gif
      20.format = png
      20.offset = 0,3
      noLink = 1
      wrap = <li class="act">|</li>
    }

    // if translation is not available:
    USERDEF1 < .NO
    USERDEF1 {
      // the grayscale effectdoes not work with some IM versions
      30 = EFFECT
      30.value = gray | gray=1 | grey | grey=1
      // the same flags like above, bleached
      40 = EFFECT
      40.value = gamma=5
      // naturally this should not be linked either
      noLink = 1
    }
  }
}
```

differences which might be important:

- I use constant values for the generated images and no blank after the comma
- I give explicit sizes for the used images
- I use color values instead of color names
- I use transparent color